# Should one normalize the "features" in binary fingerprints?

Tags: molecular-modeling, machine-learning

In regression models to predict chemical compounds' activities, fingerprints are often used as features. **Should one normalize a fingerprint feature to be in the 0-1 range?**

Comment: I've posted this question in a chat room with some machine learning experts, and there's a question about whether you're doing ordinary least-squares regression or maximum likelihood estimation procedures. Perhaps you can join that discussion and we can converge closer to an answer for you: https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/56950547#56950547

Comment: I think the question would benefit from some more detail on the sorts of compounds and features you are looking at. The question is definitely on-topic here, but if you don't wind up getting a response, you may also want to try AI SE or Cross Validated.